# How to get the decision function from svm_model

Tags: machine-learning, svm, libsvm

Say I have a feature vector `[v1,v2,v3]`,
then I have a decision function `a*v1+b*v2+c*v3 =d`
how do I get the values `(a,b,c,d)` using the inforrmation  in `svm_model`?

I saw that these two fields in `svm_model`

```
public double[][] sv_coef;// coefficients for SVs in decision functions (sv_coef[k-1][l])
public double[] rho;// constants in decision functions (rho[k*(k-1)/2])
```

I suspect it could be essential for getting the decision function.

Answer (score 0):

There is also a `SVs` field in `svm_model`. Your decision function is `wv+b=0`, where `v = [v1,v2,v3]`. Then,

```
w = SVs' * msv_coef;
b = -.rho;
```

For multi-class SVM, you may also need another field called `Label`

```
if Label(1) == -1
  w = -w;
  b = -b;
end
```

Check the [FAQ](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/faq.html#f804) part for more details.